# CoffeeScript 2 Dimensional Array Usage

Tags: coffeescript

I feel like I'm missing something with CoffeeScript and 2 dimensional arrays.  I'm simply attempting to make a grid of spaces (think checkers).  After some searching and a discovery with the arrays.map function, I came up with this:

```
@spaces = [0...20].map (x)->
  [0...20].map (y) ->
    new Elements.Space()
```

And this seems to work great, I have a nice 2 dimensional array with my Space object created in each.  But now I want to send the created space constructor the x,y location.  Because I'm two layers deep, I lost the `x` variable when I entered the map function for `y`.

Ideally I would want to do something like:

```
@spaces = [0...20].map (x)->
  [0...20].map (y) ->
    new Elements.Space(x, y)
```

or something that feels more natural to me like:

```
for row in rows
  for column in row
    @spaces[row][column] = new Elements.Space(row, column)
```

I'm really open to any better way of doing this.  I know how I would do it in standard JavaScript, but really would like to learn how to do it in CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your first attempt with `map` is a valid way to do it.  You don't actually lose `x`, because closures.  So there's nothing wrong with your second code block:

```
@spaces = [0...20].map (x)->
  [0...20].map (y) ->
    new Elements.Space(x, y)
```

The for loop version of this is also pretty simple:

```
@spaces = for x in [0...20]
  for y in [0...20]
    new Elements.Space(x, y)
```

Remember, everything is an expression.  So this works (and might be a bit clearer than the `map` version).

Comment: The for-loop version also doesn't have to create the arrays just to call `map` on them, the `for x in [0...20]` translate directly into JavaScript for-loops.

Comment: Thank you!  Me translating what I had to something simpler for this question ended up fixing it.  From what I saw in the Chrome debugger, x was undefined.  But it works!